# Does anyone have code to make the mouse cursor a cross/plus sign in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-toolkit

Does anyone have code to make the mouse cursor a cross/plus sign in silverlight?

when I click on one draw button then I want cursor as cross/plus sign do how can I implement in the silver light ?

Comment: The basic answer is no, however your goals might be helped if you described the reason for the requirement since that would allow room for work arounds that work for that requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Its not actually possible to set the Cursor image to anything other than the set of images specified by the `Cursors` class.  Its quite a limited set.

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight Tip of the Day #28: How to Implement a Custom Mouse Cursor
http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2010/03/16/81607.aspx